# Floating Label style doesn't apply when FloatingLabelBehavior.always

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

This is quite a straightforward problem. This `floatingLabelBehavior` was added almost 2 years ago but no one has raised an issue that if you set a specific style to `floatingLabelStyle`, it doesn't appear as the correct style unless you click on the field or when the field is focused.

Anyone found a solution to this? or should I just search for solutions on how to focus the fields automatically without showing soft keyboard?

Comment: Check out the here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/55651 it fix the issue

Comment: not related. when using FormField it does follow the floating label style but TextFormField it doesn't. weird.